# Is it possible to force the Google Maps API to use a specific Transit Provider

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps, gtfs

I am writing an app (in react) that provides an ETA to a user on a train for when they will reach the next NJTransit station based on their location.

I would like to use Google Maps, but I do not see a way to ensure it will only use NJTransit. For instance, if I were to ask for directions from Newark to New York, it is possible Google Maps would give a route using the Path.

I have the GTFS data, but calculating it off of that would be inaccurate due to lack of delay information. NJTransit seems to have a real-time GTFS feed, but it is designed for servers and this has to be completely client based.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience using google maps api, you have limited ways that you can form a request. To make routes you will have to use `gooole routes` so you can take a look over there on how you can tweak your request to have the best response. Hope it helps, if not let me know